# alternatives to GCC 3.4.3 option -fstack-protector-all?

Tags: c, arm, gcc3

I'm trying to set option `-fstack-protector-all` in GCC 3.4.3 compiler for enabling some stack smashing protection scenarios. However when compiling with this i got 
*error: unrecognized command line option "-fstack-protector-all"*
. So seems this option isn't implemented in GCC 3.4.3 ?? or Am I missing something ?

If it is not implemented in older GCC compiler what is the best / easiest alternative to this ?

Or maybe some useful code pattern to implement stack-smashing protector in C code itself ?

Thanks

Comment: GCC 3.4.3 is more than seven years old. It's time you upgraded.

Comment: We can't, because we use some vendor libs which isn't compatible with GCC4...

Comment: You pay them for that? Would be time that they adapt their product to the present.

Comment: We have some their devices bought, but they don't send/have/develop? new firmware library upgrades for old devices. Yeah, it would be good if they do so, cause we can't afford to buy new devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be only one minor version off a gcc version that seems to be able to provide you with this particular smash protection. I found this when googling:

http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/projects/security/ssp/

Maybe you could upgrade to that one (one minor number up) and still be compatible with your vendor?

Additionally, as at least for a number of years canary values are default set in gcc (no need to use the option you mention), have you looked at the disassembly of a simple program? If you see some storing/loading from a (gs) location near end of stack, it's already implemented.

Comment: Oups. That's how it's implemented in x86 Linux. But you probably would have a similar copying to and fro a protected memory region in ARM as well.

Comment: About default smashing protection setting - it is enabled by default on _SOME_ systems, but not for all.     For example - SSP is disabled in Linux Mint.